# How Can I Restart My Flutter App With Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using the getx package in my application and there is something I am wondering about. Is it possible to reset all states of my app using getx?
So it's kind of like a restart.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Future<void> logoutUser() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear(); //clearing my token data
    await Get.deleteAll(force: true); //deleting all controllers
    Phoenix.rebirth(Get.context!); // Restarting app
    Get.reset(); // resetting getx

  }
```

used [flutter_phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) library to restart the app.
Deleted all GetX controllers using `Get.deleteAll(force: true);`

Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform a full OS-level restart, you can use the "[restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app)" plugin, which utilizes native APIs to restart the app. With this method, you won't have to worry about manually resetting states as the app restarts entirely from the beginning.